# Can anitmatter be scattered in other parts of time?

Tags: time, big-bang, antimatter

Is it possible that during the Big Bang, the matter and antimatter was scattered in the spacetime, along the time axis, as well, not just in space?

(I am not sure, how to ask this properly, I hope this makes sense!)

As we travel through time, and reach patches of that scattered matter, suddenly some matter may appear out of nowhere, or some antimatter.

Answer (score 2):

There is no evidence - either direct or indirect - of matter or antimatter suddenly appearing anywhere in our universe. The only theoretical mechanism that we know of that could connect distant points in spacetime is an [Einstein-Rosen bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole). This has also never been observed, and it has such unusual properties that many physicists think it is physically impossible anyway.

Without observational evidence or a plausible mechanism, the idea of scattering matter/antimatter through time is pure speculation, not physics.

Comment: The question is if we know of any plausible mechanism for this to happen!